# Gradle dependencies - Latest snapshot

Tags: groovy, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle multi-project build.

In one project, I have defined some dependencies on other JARs, and have used the '+' to always depend on the latest version of the JAR e.g.

```
runtime group:'com.app', name: 'core', version: '+'
```

This works great, and anytime I re-build a version of the core project, this project picks up the latest JAR as expected.

However, this only seems to work when I explicitly build the JAR with a version - but SNAPSHOT builds are not picked up.

For example, if I have `core-1.0.1.jar` then my project uses that, then I build `core-1.0.2.jar` and the project will pcik up that new jar, however if I then build a snapshot version of the jar like `core-SNAPSHOT.jar`, then the project remains using 1.0.2 version.

(I know its not good to depend on snapshots - but I will be running this with my CI server building the numbered versions and installing to the repo, but when in dev I want to be able to build adhoc snapshot builds and be able to use them without changing config)

Is this possible? I have not been able to find any info about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, snapshots always include a version number (e.g. `1.0.3-SNAPSHOT`). I think it's not picking it up because as it stands, `SNAPSHOT` is considered a lower version than `1.0.2`.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I assume to get this to work locally I will have to put in some kind of hack whereby dev just builds 999-snapshot or something so it is always taken as latest then?

Comment: If you use Maven snapshots, it's best to use them in the Maven way (x-SNAPSHOT while working towards version x). An alternative is to bump the version on every build and use `+` (or `latest.integration` in Gradle 1.8) to select the latest version.