# gradle compile does not seem to be able to resolve "-SNAPSHOT" dependencies even though they exist in artifactory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I cannot resolve dependencies that I have published to my own artifactory server ending in "-SNAPSHOT."

I get the error:

```
Could not find com.company:common:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
com.company:Intranet:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I thought by increasing the dependency versions to 1.0.2 or greater per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131411/gradle-dependencies-latest-snapshot) that it might solve the problem but it had no effect.

I have turned off unique version numbers (timestamp) on the snapshot repo. I can also see that the artifacts are indeed in my artifactory, and I do not have typos. As soon as I publish a regular version such as '1.0.0', I am able to resolve them. Here is part of my build.gradle: (And yes, I am not using the artifactory plugin, I hope to move to that soon.)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.company'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

def commonDep = "com.company:common:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
def newCommonDep = "com.company:new-common:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

configurations {
    deployerJars
    overlayJars
}

//From the maven plugin
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        uniqueVersion = false
        configuration = configurations.deployerJars
        snapshotRepository(url:"${artifactory_contextUrl}/ident-snapshot") {
        authentication(userName: "${artifactory_user}", password:       
        "${artifactory_password}")
    }
    repository(url:"${artifactory_contextUrl}/ident-release") {
        authentication(userName: "${artifactory_user}", password: 
       "${artifactory_password}")
    }
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/central"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
    }
}
}

dependencies {

//jar used for maven deploy
deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"

//grab newCommon and common war to do an overlay with the intranet war
overlayJars commonDep + '@war', newCommonDep + '@war'

compile commonDep + ':classes'
compile newCommonDep + ':classes'

providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was totally my own fault but nevertheless I will answer my own question. The "central" repo defined did not actually contain the snapshot repo where the "-SNAPSHOT" was located. I had thought it did. "Central" in our companies context is a virtual repo containing a few repos, but not the snaphot repo. I implemented a solution I found [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/maven_publish_specify_a_repo_as_being_a_snapshot_repo). Or I could have just declared the repository alongside the "central" one.

Answer (score 3):

From the error output, it seems that some dependency is incorrectly declared as `"com-company-common:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"` instead of `"com-company:common:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`.

Comment: I saw that, but I assumed that that was a bug in the output itself. Im not sure how that could be, as the variables "commonDep" and "newCommonDep" (which are used in the dependency closure) dont seem to have that format. However, I'll take a closer look at my build script.

Comment: You can verify which dependency coordinates are used by turning on `--info` or `--debug` logging.

Comment: This seems to not be a problem specific to gradle, but maven as well. I set up the project as a maven project and am getting the same error.

Comment: I also just realized that I had made a typo when putting that error down. I had replaced the name of our real company with "company" and in so doing, had inadvertently put a "-" where ":" should have been.